# I don't have it

Tags: word-usage

My friend asked for me for a scale. So I said:

> 1. Sorry but I don't have it. (can there be an alternative?)

Is the use of "have" natural?

And: Can there be another "more natural" way (alternative) to describe this?

Comment: Normal scale. "Like a 15cm scale". "30cm" scale. @Michael Harvey.

Comment: So is it right? And any alternatives?

Comment: Sounds like you want **ruler**, rather than **scale**.

Comment: @SamBC See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_ruler - Technically, it's a scale to measure, a ruler to draw lines.

Comment: Well, in idiomatic British English, we never call it a scale. It's always a ruler. In fact, anyone insisting that "technically, it's a scale to measure" will be considered a more than usually annoying pedant.

Comment: Note that "I don't have **it**" is generally used when you're referring to a particular scale - one that your friend lent to you or one that she knows that you often carry with you. If she's asking for any scale at all (not a particular one), you would say, "I don't have **one**."

Answer (score 3):

I see no problem with the use of *have*. But what does sound a bit off to me is the use of *it*.

> "Do you have **a** scale?"

Here, no specific scale has been mentioned. So, rather than using *it*, I would use *one*:

> "Sorry, but I don't have **one**."

---

On the other hand, if the question *had* been about a specifically identified scale, then *it* would have been more appropriate:

> "Do you have **the** scale?"
>   "Sorry, but I don't have **it**."

Answer (score 2):

It's natural. Another way would be to say "I haven't got it".